# How to Read and Write characters using StreamReader and StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a task to implement a method that reads from StreamReader and writes it back to StreamWriter.

My implementation:

```
public static void ReadAndWriteChars(StreamReader streamReader, 
                                     StreamWriter outputWriter)
{
    // TODO #5-2. Implement the method by reading a character from the
    // StreamReader and writing it to the outputStream with 
    // StreamWriter.Write() method.
    string ch = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    char[] s = ch.ToCharArray();
    foreach (var value in s)
    {
        outputWriter.Write(value);
    }
}
```

However, it does not pass even a single test:

```
[TestCase(new char[] { })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a' })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a', 'b' })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a' })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' })]
[TestCase(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c' })]
public void ReadAndWriteChars_ArgumentsAreValid_WritesToStreamWriter(char[] chars)
{
    // Arrange
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chars);
    using var contentStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    using var contentReader = new StreamReader(contentStream);

    using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    using var outputWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);

    // Act
    WritingToStream.ReadAndWriteChars(contentReader, outputWriter);

    // Assert
    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using var outputReader = 
        new StreamReader(outputStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, -1, true);
    char[] actualChars = new char[buffer.Length];
    outputReader.Read(actualChars, 0, actualChars.Length);

    Assert.AreEqual(chars, actualChars);
}
```

Here is the debug result:

[image]

Comment: That method makes little sense. If you're going to read the entire input file as a `string`, why would then write to the output file one `char` at a time? If you're going to write by `char`, surely you would read by `char` too.

Comment: I am simply not sure how to read it by char. Is there any specific function to do that? @John

Comment: You should have read the documentation for the `StreamReader` class and that will tell you.

Comment: The StreamWriter has a buffer, until you flush that buffer, the last buffer content will not have been written to the output stream.

Comment: Because you are using a `using` declaration, the objects you are creating will not be disposed until the end of the method. If you use a `using` block instead, you can specify the end of the block for `outputWriter` before you create `outputReader`. That will ensure that the buffer is flushed without having to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I overlooked that part.

Comment: Consider just using `Stream.CopyTo`